# Linear Operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Let  $E = \{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\}$  be a basis for a vector space $V$.  Find the matrix with respect to E of the linear operator $L: V\to V$ defined by $L(v_1) = v_2, L(v_2) = v_3, L(v_3) = v_4, L(v_4) = v_1$.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Please consider rewriting your post!

Comment: I am currently trying to teach myself Linear Algebra and am having trouble with the theoretical aspect of it. I am really just confused on how to solve this problem

Answer (score 3):

$\{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\}$ is a basis for E.

$L(v_1)=v_2= 0.v_1+1.v_2+0.v_3+0.v_4$

$L(v_2)=v_3= 0.v_1+0.v_2+1.v_3+0.v_4$

$L(v_3)=v_4= 0.v_1+0.v_2+0.v_3+1.v_4$

$L(v_4)=v_1= 1.v_1+0.v_2+0.v_3+0.v_4$

$$\left( \begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)_{4\times4}$$

Answer (score 0):

I might help if you view a matrix $A$ as
$$
A=\left( \begin{matrix}
a_{11} & a_{12} & ... & a_{1n} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & ... & a_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
a_{m1} & a_{m2} & ... & a_{mn} \end{matrix}\right)_{m\times n}
=
\left( \begin{matrix} 
Av_1 & Av_2 & ... & Av_n \end{matrix}\right)
$$

where $Av_i$ is the image of $v_i$. For example if you want $A$ to send $v_2$ to $v_3$, you just put $v_3$, written in the correct basis, in the $2^{nd}$ column of $A$. (Like in Mr. Babai's excellent answer)